# Google Service Apis for PHP list all subscriptions instead of get

Tags: php, google-api-client, subscriptions

I'm getting this error while trying to query for Google Subscriptions (monthly renewal):

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/com.iwitness.android/purchases/subscriptions/monthly_sub_2.99/tokens/12999763169054705758.1378906769207703: (400) Invalid Value
```

I'm using Google Service APIs for PHP, and wants to have a cronjob that verify against Subscriptions in order to disable/enable/extend expiration days.

I wonder if we have any other apis that could list out all subscriptions instead of doing this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($this->googleClient);
$subs = $service
    ->purchases_subscriptions
    ->get(
        'com.iwitness.android',
        'monthly_sub_2.99',
        '12999763169054705758.1378906769207703'
    );
...
```

Or, are there any way to get rid of "(400) Invalid Value" error? I tested with Android publisher v1/v2 and have same problem.
Please help.

Comment: Try to echo out the returning error message and see if you can get a more indepth response as to what you are missing.

Comment: Yeah, I did, and here is the error (doesn't make any sense at all):
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}